# Devise AJAX - POST request : current_user is null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise, cross-domain

I try to develop a single page application with authentication. I use Devise (Rails) and AngularJS.
For some different reasons my rails application and my angularjs application are not on the same server. So, I have to handle cross domain issues... And I can't send X-CSRF-Token in my header.
I can correctly  sign in and sign out and send GET request without problem. In my rails controllers, I can use current_user, it's correctly set.
However, when I send a POST request, current_user is null. It seems my session_id is not sent. The problem is due to cross domain, because if I send my ajax request from the same server, it is OK.

I think, I have 2 solutions : 
- Don't use authentication cookie-based, but use token
- Put front-end and back-end on the same server.

Other ideas ? Why current_user is null when I send a POST request from cross domain ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could send the CSRF token in the headers HOWEVER it's a bad practice that exposes some security holes ([issue thread on github explaining why](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/9405))

Safest way to go about this is to disable [CSRF](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html) all together:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # or use Api::BaseController < ApplicationController if you are namespacing
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
end
```

**AND** use token based authentication that you can either [implement yourself](http://railscasts.com/episodes/352-securing-an-api) or use devise's :token_authenticatable. You will have to configure AngularJS to send the token either in params or headers. Here's a snippet I use for having rails figure out if the token is in the headers or params.

```
class Api::BaseController < ApplicationController
  prepend_before_filter :get_auth_token 

  private
  def get_auth_token
    if auth_token = params[:auth_token].blank? && request.headers["X-AUTH-TOKEN"]
      params[:auth_token] = auth_token
    end
  end
end
```

So in the end how it works is:

1. Client uses login method that you defined to authenticate
2. Obtains authentication token from the server
3. Uses the token in each subsequent request for the purpose of authorization

Comment: Thx, Is :authentication_token compatible with oAuth2 for SSO authentication (like Facebook) ? By the way, can I use oAuth for manage my token ?

Comment: Yes you can make it work together. It's just another type of authentication you would attach to your user here's a nice rails casts episode http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1. If you treat your own app as another authentication provider then I believe it is possible but not sure if it would be a benefit at all. The thing is devise already has a system for managing its own tokens.